# flash objects must have the 'source' and 'picture' attributes

Tags: facebook, flash, post, publishing

This started happening today. Yesterday everything worked just fine and we didn't publish new code since week ago.

Go to: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=151774588251426&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fwidget.nextwidgets.com%2fnewsfeed%2flanding%2fshared%2f4070&link=https%3a%2f%2fwidget.nextwidgets.com%2ftrack%2fredirect%2fpromote%3finvid%3d0%26wid%3d4070%26lc%3den&display=page

Usually we would see standard share dialog. But now we are getting:

**Error with publishing**

**flash objects must have the 'source' and 'picture' attributes**

How do we fix this?

Comment: I just compared Object Debugger results from a youtube video and the share link from reproduction steps. Everything matches perfectly. In addition youtube has open graph warning while our link is parsed perfectly fine. Yet youtube works but our link doesn't. Please help!

Comment: It looks like we aren't only one who have the problem: http://bubble-witch-saga.se/no-it-is-not-just-you-the-mini-games-cant-be-posted/

Comment: After I added source and picture params it started working. But now dimensions of the widget are not right.

Comment: Another thread having the same issue:

http://www.topgamesforum.com/sending-out-post-request-t718690.html